# ExcelファイルをMySQLデータベースにインポートする方法について教えて下さい。

Tags: mysql, excel

お世話になります。※1 データベース初学者です。

ExcelファイルをMySQLに読み込む方法についてお聞きしたいと思っております。

[ExcelファイルをMySQLデータベースにインポートする方法](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ja/mysql/excel%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92mysql%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/966948694/)

上記のサイトを読みながら下記のようなExcelの表をMySQLに読み込んで操作したいと考えております。

[image: MySQLに読み込みたいExcelの表]

まずは、MySQLのコマンドプロンプトに `SHOW DATABASES;` を入力したら、下記のような出力がされたら幸いです。

外部から特定のファイルを読み込むコマンドがMySQLにあると思うのですが、Googleで検索をかけても分からなかったのでこちらで質問させていただきました。

```
Country   |   Amount   |   Qty
----------------------------------
America   |   93       |   0.60
Greece    |   9377     |   0.80
Australia |   9375     |   0.80
```

※２　手順通りにやれば、解決致しました。ご回答ありがとうございます。

編集点
※１　自分が初心者であることを追加したこと。
※２　自己解決したこと。

Comment: 「外部から特定のファイルを読み込むコマンドがMySQLにあると思う」とコメントされていますが、どこで確認されましたか？それともどなたかにあると回答されましたか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。「外部から特定のファイルを読み込むコマンドがMySQLにあると思う」という内容は、MySQLでExcelを操作できるのではという勝手な自分の思いこみです。

Comment: 参照しているサイトには実際の手順が書かれているように見えますが、こちらは実際に試したのでしょうか？  / 本文に追記された「初学者です」は、質問の説明ではなくあなた自身のパーソナルな情報です。どうしても記載したい場合には [プロフィールページへの記載](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/39846) を検討してください。